# How to disable zooming ability on mobile for a particular element?

Tags: css, html

I have a top menu bar and when is on mobile if I try to zoom my website then my menu bar is zooming as well. I don't want to zoom the menu bar

Answer (score 0):

You could globally disable zooming, capture the zoom gestures in Javascript and rescale the rest of your website accordingly.